# French Character Turn Into Question Marks; Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, character-encoding

I have a csv file which contains french characters/accents including: É, ê, è etc, referring to some french city and street names. I have tried several encoding options on the read_csv and to_csv functions in Pandas including:

```
 df=pd.read_csv(FilePath, encoding='latin-1' )
```

also:

```
encoding='utf-8'
encoding='latin-1'
encoding='utf-8-sig'
encoding='iso-8859-1'
```

I have also tried not specifying any encoding.

I am using Python 2.7 and the Pandas Module. I have read that Python 3 does better with encoding but that is not currently an option.

The french characters turn into questions marks (?) when the output file is opened in excel or notepad++, and now due to trying to fix that issue they begin as questions marks when I read in the original file or when I open that original file in excel or notepadd++. Before they showed up as normal french characters.

Example data and code:

```
City    Address1_Particule  Address1_Street Address1_StreetType
Montr? V    Des BRISES DU FLEUVE    ALL?
Montr? V    Des BRISES DU FLEUVE    ALL?
Montr? V    Des BRISES DU FLEUVE    ALL?
Montr? V    Des BRISES DU FLEUVE    ALL?

#create dataframe
df=pd.read_csv(FilePath, encoding='latin-1' )

for streetType in StreetTypeList:
    for pretype in StreePreTypeList:
        df[pretype]=''
  # Change street type french from short to long form  and into new column
        df.loc[dfCAS[streetType]=='AV', [pretype]]='AVENUE'
        df.loc[dfCAS[streetType]=='AVE', [pretype]]='AVENUE'
        df.loc[dfCAS[streetType]=='BOUL', [pretype]]='BOULEVARD'
        df.loc[dfCAS[streetType]=='CH', [pretype]]='CHEMIN'

df.to_csv(OutputPath, encoding='latin-1'
```

I hope to create an output csv file where french characters display properly.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
df = pd.read_excel(FilePath, encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this link might be helpful for people to find all encoding types. Please refer to this link:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

I was looking for Czech language characters and found out that the following encoding should work for czech characters:
iso8859_2, iso-8859-2, latin2, L2 (Central and Eastern Europe)

Similarly other language characters can be used with correct encoding from this list.